# Angular 4 - Apply different param pipe filter

Tags: angular

I have a pipe filter for one html table

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'filterDescrip'})
export class FilterDescripPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(particulars: any, searchText: any): any {
    if(searchText == null) return particulars;
    return particulars.filter(function(particular){
      if(searchText.match(/[a-z]/g))
      {
        return particular.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1;
      } else {
        return particular.description.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1;
      }
      //return particular.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1;
    })
  }
}
```

How I can to send from the html code diferentes params to filter, using a condition:

```
<tr *ngFor="let particular of particulars | filterDescrip: paramSearch | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}">
```

Can I to use a condition inside of:  | filterDescrip: {}, maybe with a expression, how would be?

I have two variables, I need the following: if variable paramSearch is empty or undefined:

```
| filterDescrip: searchDescText
```

but if paramSearch has content:

```
| filterDescrip: paramSearch
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let particular of particulars | filterDescrip: (paramSearch || searchDescText) | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}">
```